# Clean boost temporary files after build

Tags: c++, boost

After the boost library build the main directory is ~9GB. How can I remove the temporary/intermediate files (and keep the compiled library files)?

I use Windows for my project.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of cleaning up, I can recommend using

```
./b2 --build-dir=/path/to/temp/combustible
```

to build. This puts all the intermediate/temporary files in a separate location. I always put it in tmpfs ("ram disk") so it's gone after a reboot anyways. But you can trivially just remove that build-dir once you lost interest.

The approach works on all platforms. You can keep the intermediates until after all your build(s) complete so you profit maximally of any shared intermediate files.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stage` command and then delete intermediate files, like

```
bjam ... --stagedir=... stage
erase /q /s bin.v2
```